# How to detect voice/singing in music?

Tags: gratis, python, music, voice-recognition

I am looking for a free command line (Linux) tool, or a python package, that checks an audio file (music) for voice/singing in it. I have a lot of music pieces; some are with singing and some are without. I am looking for some code that can analyze a music file and that can tell me, how much singing is in that music file, or if there singing at all, or something like that.

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git clone https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad`

From README:

> This is a python interface to the WebRTC Voice Activity Detector
> (VAD).  It is compatible with Python 2 and Python 3.
>
> A [VAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection)
> classifies a piece of audio data as being voiced or unvoiced. It can
> be useful for telephony and speech recognition.
>
> The VAD that Google developed for the [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/)
> project is reportedly one of the best available, being fast, modern
> and free.

Answer (score 1):

I came across an open source Python project for VAD (Voice Activity Detection) which can be found [here](https://github.com/marsbroshok/VAD-python). This can be installed by running the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/marsbroshok/VAD-python.git
```

Given an audio file, the system analyzes it and outputs detected speech regions as intervals of time. It is also simple to use and can easily be converted into a Python script which runs from the command line.

Here is some example code used to plot detected speech regions of a given audio file:

```
from vad import VoiceActivityDetector

filename = '/Users/user/wav-sample.wav'
v = VoiceActivityDetector(filename)

v.plot_detected_speech_regions()
```

Hope this helps :)